# Equivalent hibernate query for given sql query

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql

Hibernate newbie alert. What will be the equivalent hibernate query for following mentioned sql query?

```
SELECT DISTINCT meetupid 
FROM   meetups 
   INNER JOIN friends 
           ON meetups.participantphonenumber = friends.friendphonenumber 
              AND friends.userphonenumber = :phoneNumber
```

What I have tried :

```
SELECT DISTINCT meetUp.meetUpId 
FROM MeetUp meetUp 
   INNER JOIN Friendship friends 
           ON meetUp.participantPhoneNumber = friends.friendPhoneNumber 
              AND friends.userPhoneNumber = :phoneNumber
```

But this gives **`ERROR:  Path expected for join!`**.

Note : Tables **`meetups`** and **`friends`** are not related by any foreign key.

TIA

Comment: You tried something? try something first!.

Comment: For example something like: `select distinct m.meetupid from Meetups m join m.friends fr where fr.upserphonenumber = 9876543210`. Also if you need some help, please add your entities.

Comment: If the tables `meetups` and `friends` are not related in any form (@OnetoMany and similars), you can not use `HQL`, and your SQL is the way to go. Also remember, when using `HQL` the foreing keys are not relevant, only the annotations (or xml config) in the entities. For this reason, you can not specify the join point between two entities, you must use a atribute of one of the entities, see my comment: `meetUp.friends`, for make this work you need a atribute in `meetUp` like this: `@OneToMany(...) List<Friendship> friends`

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good case for using HQL as @AVolpe says in his comment. But you should be able to do it in HQL using a subquery. But really ... map it or use SQL.

```
select m.meetupid from Meetup m  
    where m.participantPhoneNumber in (
        select f.friendPhoneNumber from Friendship f
            where f.userPhone = :phoneNumber)
```